# Apache Giraph 1.0.0 - How is memory allocated for vertices?

Tags: java, memory, giraph

Recently, I was successfully able to create a custom vertex class in which each vertex has a LongWritable id, and this id is also its own value. My Giraph program runs successfully on a small vertex set (100,000 vertices) and the program completes and outputs expected values. However, when I increase the volume to 30 million vertices, the program hangs when the total memory is maxed out (heap size is 1.5 GB per mapper). Since my vertex class only holds an id and value (8 + 8 = 16 bytes) as well as emanating edges (on average 8*8*2 = 128 bytes), I don't understand why memory consumption is so high. From the log message below, the memory is max'd out at 4.5 million vertices at 1363 MB, so each vertex is taking up 317 bytes when Giraph runs. What extra data structures within Giraph are causing bytes/vertex to be so high?

```html
readVertexInputSplit: Loaded 4500000 vertices at 90245.3768041096 vertices/sec 0 edges at 0.0 edges/sec Memory (free/total/max) = 187.52M / 1363.00M / 1365.50M

waitFor: Future result not ready yet java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@5f7bd943
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an answer for anyone looking for one.

Try to change the way Giraph holds the partitions.
There is a large overhead if the default one is used.
Use `org.apache.giraph.partition.ByteArrayPartition` instead, which effectively holds only your data as a byte array, not in a wrapped form. Java has an overhead for holding the objects which in your case is very apparent as you have many small objects - thus the waste is also high.

Also, in general, running small mappers is *not* recommended.
It is better to have a few powerful nodes (about 10 cores and 30-60GB RAM) rather than dozens of small ones.

There may be a magnitude of other reasons but I cannot say without the details.